# Reading PCI MSICAP register

Tags: linux, hardware, linux-device-driver, pci

I am trying to enable multiple MSI on my PCI card where in before enabling the same i read pci_config_space() MSICAP + 2h: MC – Message Signaled Interrupt Message Control.

The way i am doing is as follows

```
u16 val;
int pos = 0x50;
pci_read_config_word(dev, pos + PCI_MSI_FLAGS, &val);
printk("\n  val = %x", val);
val |= 0x51;
pci_write_config_word(dev, pos + PCI_MSI_FLAGS, val);
pci_read_config_word(dev, pos + PCI_MSI_FLAGS, &val);
printk("\n After pci_enable  val = %x", val);
```

Firstly is this the right way of accessing MSI CAP + 2 offset?

I am reading the value as 0x80 which says only one MSI is supported but HW spec says it supports 16MSI's and the expected value is 88.

Taking HW spec to it's truest, when i enable more than one MSI as follows

```
ret = pci_enable_msi_block(dev, 2);
```

Value of "ret" is 1 which says my request for multiple MSI failed.
When checked in kernel code, this is the path where it fails and this says MSI CAP was 0x00.

```
292 #define  PCI_MSI_FLAGS_QMASK    0x0e    /* Maximum queue size available */

670         pci_read_config_word(dev, pos + PCI_MSI_FLAGS, &msgctl);
671         maxvec = 1 << ((msgctl & PCI_MSI_FLAGS_QMASK) >> 1);
672         if (nvec > maxvec)
673                 return maxvec;
```

Am i missing something here?